# PHP Post parameters to another server

Tags: php

I work on something that I've never come across before and I would like for your advice. I need to pass a HTTP to another server in order to automatically insert variables such as username and password.to clear this more and be more specific I need to pass as I said the username and password through http://192.123456789:8080/something-server/admin/add-user. The process is set when I click a button on my admin panel and then automatically inputs the data to the other server as well. I use a Boolean method to to make something active or not as it is shown below. The thing is that when I click "change" I need to make post those parameters to the other server.

```
   if ($get["$i"] == 1) {

    echo("<td style='color:green;'>Yes</td>");

    $changeto = 0;
    }
else {

    echo("<td style='color:red;'>No</td>");

    $changeto = 1;

    }

echo("<td><a href='visible.php?

username=".$user."&user=".$get['id_license']."&licence=".$i."&to=".$changeto."'>Change</a>

</td>");

echo("</tr>");
```

Comment: look up on creating http streams with php. also, the other server need to have some kind of API endpoint ready for your server-sever communication...cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have CURL enabled, you could try something like this.
Ofcourse replace the params and the URL with the one youŕe using.

You can ofcourse find a way to generate the params dymanicly to a string.

```
<?php
//
// A very simple PHP example that sends a HTTP POST to a remote site
//

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/file.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

print_r($server_output);

curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Thats pretty much understandable. From the research i have made i found out that curl is the way to deal with this. However I dont know how to adapt this on my above code because i said while i click the change button i need the curl do the rest. how can i combine the code??

Comment: You should be able to just copy the code and use it in your visible.php, I guess visible.php is on server A and it needs to post to server B right? You could just use this script.

Comment: No problem man.
Just flag it as the correct answer if it helped you.

Comment: I need to as you something. the postvar is the variable i am sending to the other server and the value is the variable corresponding to the other server??

Comment: or postvar1=value1 is the actual query that the browser creates during the posting process?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but The postvar is the variable name and the value the value.

So on the other server you could fetch them like $_POST['postvar1'] it would contain a string "value1" in this example